# F.select input not saving value on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an f.select input on my Rails app that comes from this helper method.

```
def option_groups_from_collection_for_select(collection, group_method, group_label_method, option_key_method, option_value_method)
  collection.map do |group|
    option_tags = options_from_collection_for_select(
      group.send(group_method), option_key_method, option_value_method)

    content_tag(:optgroup, option_tags, :label => group.send(group_label_method))
  end.join.html_safe
end
```

The select in the view is shown below.

```
<%= f.select(:type_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :types, :category, :id, :name)) %>
```

When saving the Post, the correct type_id is getting saved, but when I go and edit the post, the select doesn't show the currently selected item like it's supposed to. I'm assuming something is wrong in my code.

Here is my category model

```
has_many :posts
has_many :types, :order => "name"
```

and here is my type model

```
belongs_to :category
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to provide a 5th argument which is the selected key. Try the code below:

```
<%= f.select(:type_id, option_groups_from_collection_for_select(@categories, :types, :category, :id, :name, f.object.type_id)) %>
```

`f.object.type_id` returns the type_id attribute of the object passed in the form if it has one. Otherwise, it would be nil and will not have anything selected.

Comment: Thanks @Gjaldon! That works perfectly! To those who see this, you also need to add the selected_key on your helper method

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found that I had simply misspelled the object's name in my controller file.  It did not save because the matching object could not be found.